# Find this limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^7-\int_{x^2}^{x^3} \text{sin}(t^2)dt}{\text{tg}(x^6)}$

Tags: limits

Please tell me how to calculate this limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x^7-\displaystyle{\int_{x^2}^{x^3} \text{sin}(t^2)dt}}{\text{tg}(x^6)}
$$

I want to apply L'Hopital's rule, but the problem is that the numerator contains an integral with variable limits...

*Try expanding the integral in a series. Or apply the mean value theorem for the integral? In this case, does the one-sided nature of the limit affect?*

Comment: @SineoftheTime Leibniz formula (derivative of product)?

Comment: "the problem is that the numerator contains an integer with variable limits..." -- So what? Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule.
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t
= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \int_a^{h(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_a^{g(x)} f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t
= \cdots
$$

Comment: Well, the usual Leibniz formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule, but there’s a limit, isn’t it?

Comment: @SineoftheTime 

I meant that if the numerator contains an integral, and it itself is under the limit sign, can’t I immediately use Leibniz’s rule? I did not do this, since the integral itself is in the number of the limit, where the argument tends to zero...

Comment: if you want to apply L'H rule, you can use Leibniz rule and take the derivative of the numerator. However, using Taylor series is faster

Comment: @SineoftheTime

Maybe the Taylor series expansion is more expedient, I'll think about it then..., thanks!

Comment: this is an interesting question, if you edit it adding your attemt it may be left open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to l'Hospital by series expansion

$$\int_{x^2}^{x^3} \text{sin}(t^2)dt=-\frac{x^6}3+o(x^6)$$

then

$$\frac{2x^7-\displaystyle{\int_{x^2}^{x^3} \text{sin}(t^2)dt}}{\text{tg}(x^6)}=\frac{2x^7+\frac{x^6}3+o(x^6)}{x^6+o(x^6)}=\frac{2x+\frac{1}3+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to \frac 13$$

Comment: Thanks for alternative way for obatin solution!

Answer (score 2):

As
PrincessEev
said, you can apply  L'Hopital's rule by considering $$(\int_{x^2}^{x^3} \sin(t^2)dt)'\\=(x^3)' \ \sin(t^2)|_{t=x^3}-(x^2)'\sin(t^2)|t=x^2\\
(x^3)'\sin((x^3)^2)-(x^2)'\sin((x^2)^2)\\=(3x^2)\sin(x^6)-(2x)\sin(x^4)$$and when $x$ tends to zero it will be approx to $\sim 3x^8-2x^5$

Comment: And If I try to evaluate 

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{14x^6 - 3x^8 + 2x^5}{(6x^5)/cos^2(x^6)} 
$$

I obatin 1/3. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @factor $x^5$ and simplify, then you will obtain $\frac 26$

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}(\tan x) /x=1$ we can write the desired limit as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2x^7-\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\sin t^2\,dt}{x^6}$$ We can split this limit into two terms (based on numerator) and the first term tends to $0$ so that desired limit equals the limit of expression $$\frac{1}{x^6}\int_0^{x^2}\sin t^2\,dt-\frac{1}{x^6}\int_0^{x^3}\sin t^2\,dt$$ The first term is even function of $x$ and hence it is sufficient to consider $x\to 0^+$ and then using substitution $u=t^3$ the first term equals $$\frac{1}{3x^6}\int_0^{x^6}\frac{\sin u^{2/3}}{u^{2/3}}\,du$$ Since the integrand tends to $1$ as $u\to 0$ by fundamental theorem of calculus the above expression tends to $1/3$. Considering $x\to 0^-$ and $x\to 0^+$ separately and using substitution $u=t^2$ we can prove that $$\frac{1}{x^6}\int_0^{x^3}\sin t^2\,dt\to 0$$ and hence the desired limit is $1/3$.